# Enforce attribute addition for all classes that implement an interface

Tags: c#, interface, attributes, enforcement

Let's say I have the simplest of interfaces for all components in my program.

```
public interface IComponent
{               
}
```

I know that every single component to be written for the project has to implement this interface, and I know that all of these components will be saved to disk using C#'s `BinaryFormatter`. That means that every component has to be decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute. Is there a way to enforce the addition of this attribute now?

I say "now" because I can find various SO questions that tell me this isn't possible - but all of the questions I can find are from 2008. Has anything in the C# spec changed since then? Or do I have to use one of the workarounds described in the old answers?

Comment: The oldest C# question I can find on Stack Overflow is from July 2008. How did you find answers to your question that are from _before_ 2008? Lots has changed in the C# spec, but nothing that would change how attributes are used at compile-time (i.e. they mostly aren't...there are only a few exceptions, known specifically to the compiler). You should close your question as a duplicate of one of the existing answers you've found, or just delete it altogether.

Comment: The "or earlier" part is misleading since SO was started in 2008. I'll close the question if your comment is indeed the answer: nothing has change and there's no way to enforce attribute decoration. But I deemed it prudent to ask, since a lot of things have changed since C# 3.0 and 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could write unit tests that picks ups all implementation of `IComponent` from your library using reflection and checks if they have the `Serializable` attribute on them. I don't belive anything new was introduced in .NET since 2008 that could make that check compile time specific, sorry.